# 8086 assembler: compare two unsigned integers and set AX to 1 (true) or 0 (false)

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I'm writing a clone of the ancient Turbo Pascal v.3 8086 compiler. I want to compare two unsigned integers and if they are equal, set ax=1 (true) else set ax=0 (false).

Given the statement

```
bool:=1=2;
```

Turbo Pascal emits

```
  mov ax,1  ; argument 1    
  cmp ax,2  ; argument 2

  mov ax,1  ; 1 = true
  jz L1     ; arguments are equal, ax=1
  dec ax    ; arguments are not equal, ax=0
L1:
  mov bool,ax
```

Yes, it works, but seems clumsy and awkward. Is there a better way in 8086?

Comment: On 386+ use instruction `setz`

Comment: You could do constant folding and eliminate everything except a `mov bool, 0` instruction.

Comment: @RossRidge the given assembly is what's generated for the top statement as an example. In the general case, it won't be able to benefit from constant folding

Comment: In the general case the original poster compiler should be performing constant folding. It's a much more general an optimization than trying to improve the code generated for one pretty specific statement with specific code like in Egor Skriptunoff's answer.

Comment: You're both correct. My contrived example should not have used literal constants (nobody in their right mind would write bool:=1=2). Note Egor Skriptunoff's use of argument1 and argument2 in his answer.  

The question wasn't intended to be about compiler optimisation: "8086 assembler: compare two unsigned integers and set AX to 1 (true) or 0 (false)".  

Setting a boolean variable to 0 or 1 following a comparison is very common. Turbo Pascal generated very, very poor code. Even BP7 (released late 1992) produces almost identical code, merely storing the result as a byte rather than a word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mov    ax,argument1
sub    ax,argument2

add    ax,-1
sbb    ax,ax
inc    ax

mov    bool,ax
```

Comment: Very cool!  

Both your code and the original are 12 bytes, so no size improvement, but it should be faster.  

I know that cycle counting is problematic, but I came up with 18 or 30 cycles for the original code depending on whether or not the branch is taken versus 17 for yours, so it seems that you should always win. Also, because your code doesn't branch, it doesn't kill the prefetch queue.